# Which framework should I use in Xamarin(.Forms) with OpenGL?

Tags: c#, opengl, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We want to create an app, which works on multiple platforms showing a lot of lines and graphics. Since we have a Xamarin license and this app will not require any native look Xamarin.Forms is our choice. On the other hand we need mentioned graphics so we are thinking about using MonoGame (since we already know this framework). The only thing in here is, we would like to use some scrollviews in overlays and maybe the appbar (navigation bar on top). For this we had some problems in our test.

Now we are unsure what to use and would like to know if there are any other approaches to use Xamarin.Forms and OpenGL in parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Xamarin.Forms` has a `OpenGLView` `View` and it can be used within a `Xamarin.Forms` page amongst other controls.

There is some examples, using `Xamarin.Forms` with this [here](https://github.com/burf2000/OpenGLXamarin).

Do note, however that this is only available in `iOS` and `Android` however.

Along with `MonoGame`, you have `Urho` which is mentioned on the `Xamarin` website that you may want to look into, link [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/root/Urho/).  As to whether `Urho` is compatible with `Xamarin.Forms` I do not know.